# SQL Server : return column values with specific pattern

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am trying to do something really cool in the SQL a table like below

Table name: `details`

```
Id      Content
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
X345    {"Primary":["Aadhaar"],"Secondary":["Driving License","Others"]}
X346    {"Primary":["Voter ID"],"Secondary":["Driving License","Others"]}
```

From the `Content` column, I would like to extract the primary details alone meaning the values in between the first `["_____"]`. Is there any way to do this?

Like this:

```
Aadhaar
Voter ID
```

I have no idea how to use regex in this SQL Server table.

Please give me some idea on how I can get it done.

Comment: I am currently in SQL-Server 2014. Dont have support.

Comment: There's a really good reason SQL Server 2016 introduced JSON support. It is not at all convenient or fast to parse JSON with native T-SQL string functions. In fact, it's so hard to do this in general that it's almost not worth bothering with. Extracting `Primary` here is only possible because you know it always appears at the start of the string; prior to 2016, there is not even support for splitting strings on a delimiter, let alone actual JSON parsing that survives (say) strings with an embedded `,`, and regexes are a no show even in the latest version.

Comment: Versions prior to SQL Server 2016 do have support for taking apart XML, and there are [some solutions online](https://sqlsunday.com/2013/05/12/converting-json-data-to-xml-using-a-t-sql-function/) that solve this problem (for some value of "solve") by converting the JSON to XML first. Not an approach I'd favor over upgrading now that JSON support is a thing, but if you had to make do this is probably better than adhoc parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Which SQL engine you are using? (SQL Server, PGSQL or MySql etc)

In general you can string function to find position and then extract data.

For SQL Server, `CHARINDEX` and `SUBSTRING` should solve your problem, in example below I have taken hard coded string but you can replace it with column name.

```
SELECT substring('{"Primary":["Aadhaar"],"Secondary":["Driving License","Others"]}' ,CHARINDEX('["Aadhaar"]', '{"Primary":["Aadhaar"],"Secondary":["Driving License","Others"]}'),14) AS Aadhar;
```

Comment: I am using SQL server. How I can query it for the entire column in a generic way? The answer you posted is exactly what I wanted. But please tell me How I can query the entire column.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation in SQL Server 2014:

```
-- This temp table is only for testing purposes:

    DECLARE @T TABLE
    (
      Id int, 
      Content varchar(max)
    )
    INSERT INTO @T Values
    (1,'{"Primary":["Aadhaar"],"Secondary":["Driving License","Others"]}'),
    (2,'{"Primary":["Voter ID"],"Secondary":["Driving License","Others"]}'),
    (3,'{"Primary":["A Much Longer Testing Case"],"Secondary":["Driving License","Others"]}')


    SELECT LEFT(SUBSTRING(Content,14,LEN(Content)),CHARINDEX('"', SUBSTRING(Content,14,LEN(Content))) - 1)
    FROM @T
```

[Live demo](https://rextester.com/KCN98341)